# The requested page "/user/password" could not be found. need to reset my password

Tags: users

I'm using Drupal 7.

For some reason my admin password on mysite wont work, when I click forgot pass word I a presented with The requested page "/user/password" could not be found.

I don't know what is causing the reset password page not to show, I thought it may be tabtamer but I disabled that by setting status to 0 in my database.

It might be a Facebook connect module as I only allow users except admin to login via Facebook but as I can't log in to my site I can't check.

How can I reset or log into my site if I do not know the password and the page to request a new one isn't working?

Comment: Did you try using Drush?

Comment: Im not using drush. The way I managed to do it was by clearing flood in my database, then creating a new user and copying that password in my database so then I could use that password.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following drush command:

```
drush uli
```